# I can't find ./usr/bin/wine executable after I installed it

Tags: installation, wine, microsoft-office

I've been trying to install Microsoft Office 2007 and seem easy using Wine but when I install Wine i just can't run it, I tried to install Wine 1.2 and 1.3 by terminal and by the center.

In the menu of apps its the Wine icon of Winetricks and Wine configure but they don't do anything.

i tried to look for the folder in my personal folder, I already know it's a hidden folder and when i press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> appear other folders but .wine
when i apply the command WINECFG in terminal appears this:

```
carlos@CARLOS-ACER:~$ winecfg
exec: 29: /usr/bin/wine: not found
```

I hope you can help me. I'm a little new
PS: sorry for my English, I'm learning and thanks for the time to read :)

Comment: If there's no file /usr/bin/wine then Wine is missing. Make sure you have Wine 1.3 installed.

Comment: Which **Ubuntu** version?  32- or 64-bit?

Comment: [What to do with questions that describe known bugs?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) this has been reported on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ia32-libs/+bug/852101) and as such is now closed.

Comment: Only if this is **confirmed** to be 32bit Wine app., on 64bit Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ia32-libs/+bug/852101

**Workaround:**

reinstall libc6-i386 by running: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libc6-i386`

Comment: This is for running 32-bit (Wine) applications on 64 bit.

Answer (score -4):

Wine is not a program that you run as you run other programs. We use wine to install Windows programs and then when we run that Windows program wine will load it and be the means of communication between the Windows program and the Linux operating system.

Look for a program called Uninstall Wine Software. Run that and click the Install button and then browse to the setup.exe file of the Windows program or whatever exe file is used to install the Windows program.

Wine will then install the program on the hard disk in .wine folder Look for a program files folder in the drive_c folder. That is where wine will put the program files.

The installation of the Windows program should put an icon for that program on the desktop. Click that icon and wine will load the program as if it was running on the Windows operating system. At least that is the theory.

A better name for Uninstall Wine Software would be Wine Add/Remove programs. But there you are.

Comment: You totally missed the point here, he can't find `/usr/bin/wine` that's the wine executable.